# Selection based on multiple criteria including compare

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a formula that will allow me to combine different selection criterias and get a value returned.

Searching Values `ID = 1` and `Date > Today()`

```
ID | Date       | Text    
---+------------+---------
 1 | 10/04/2013 | aaaaaa     
 1 | 11/04/2013 | bbbbbb    
 1 | 12/04/2014 | cccccc     
 2 | 12/04/2013 | dddddd    
 2 | 12/04/2013 | eeeeee    
 2 | 12/04/2014 | ffffff
```

Expected result: `ccccc`

With `Index(MATCH)` I can get the text I'm looking form, if I specify the exact id and date match but I would like something like `IF ID=1 and Date > Today()` return Text.

Any suggestion without VBScript coding only formula?

Answer (score 0):

This array formula can do the trick `=INDEX($C$2:$C$7,MATCH(1,IF($B$2:$B$7>TODAY(),$A$2:$A$7),0))`. 
*(Press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to make it an array formula. Make sure you see {} around it).